# ASP.NET Razor Pages Cascading Dropdown

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I want to create a dependent dropdown list in Razor Pages. In this case, the dropdowns "Manufacturer" and "PartName" should be mutually dependent. However, I only find instructions for MVC.
Maybe someone can help me to add the missing code lines... My data are based on a SQL-database.

My cshtml.cs code is:

```
 //select for manufacturer
        [BindProperty]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Bitte Beschreibung eingeben")]
        public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
        public List<string> Manufacturers { get; set; }
        public MultiSelectList ManufacturersSelectList { get; set; }

        //select for part
        [BindProperty]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Bitte Beschreibung eingeben")]
        public string PartName { get; set; }
        public List<string> PartNames { get; set; }
        public MultiSelectList PartNamesSelectList { get; set; }
 using (MyDataContext context = new MyDataContext())
            {
                Manufacturers = context.Components
                    .Select(x=>x.SManufacturer)
                    .Distinct().AsEnumerable()
                    .OrderBy(x => x)
                    .ToList();

                PartNames = context.Components
                    .Select(x=>x.STypeDescription)
                    .Distinct()
                    .AsEnumerable().OrderBy(x => x)
                    .ToList();

                ComponentMaintenanceTypes = context.ComponentMaintenanceTypes.ToList();
                ComponentSkills = context.ComponentSkills.ToList();
                Locations = context.LocationTrees.AsEnumerable()
                    .Where(x => rgx.IsMatch(x.SName) || (!x.SName.Contains("-") && x.SName.Length <= 5))
                    .Select(x=>x.SName)
                    .OrderBy(x => x)
                    .ToList();
            }

            ManufacturersSelectList = new MultiSelectList(this.Manufacturers);
            PartNamesSelectList = new MultiSelectList(this.PartNames);
```

And my cshtml is:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
                <label class="form-label">Manufacturer</label>
                <select asp-for="Manufacturer" asp-items="Model.ManufacturersSelectList" class="form-select"><option selected="" disabled="" value="">Auswählen...</option></select>
                <span asp-validation-for="Manufacturer" class="text-danger"></span>
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                    Bitte Hersteller des Ersatzteils nennen...
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label class="form-label">Part</label>
                <select asp-for="PartName" asp-items="Model.PartNamesSelectList" class="form-select"><option selected="" disabled="" value="">Auswählen...</option></select>
                <span asp-validation-for="PartName" class="text-danger"></span>
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                    Bitte Bezeichnung des Ersatzteils nennen...
                </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What part of this code isn't working for you? Or, alternatively, what part are you stuck on specifically?

Comment: The current code works. But what I would like to add is the dependency of the drop-down lists. As my results showed, this is possible with jquery and ajax but I have problems to transfer the MVC results to RacorPages because I am a beginner in asp.net .. Thank You!

Comment: Do you mean that the data from the back-end SQL query fails to be transferred to the Razor page?